# How to remove double quotes from field value in mySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table and a column of it named `office_address` have double quoted string like `"Hello World!"`. Now I want to replace that double quoted string by only string `Hello World!`. How can I do this job by mySql query.

Table Name: `client_information`

Column Name: `office_address`

I’d appreciate any light you can shed on this! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE `client_information` 
SET `office_address` = TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM `office_address`)
```

This will update your address column with leading and trailing double quotes removed.

Answer (score 1):

Use TRIM() function:

```
mysql> SELECT TRIM('"' FROM '"Hello World!"');
+---------------------------------+
| TRIM('"' FROM '"Hello World!"') |
+---------------------------------+
| Hello World!                    |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```